# In a table chart : stuck on how to sum a specific value by a chosen category

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

First of all, I'd like to make it clear that I'm a rookie and that I'm taking things one step at a time. Hope you'll help me cause I'm stuck for couple of days ;)

Here my question based on the screen
[initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt5BD.png)
I would like to sum all duration field by host. Initialy, the duration field does not exists so I created it with the powerfull regexp function based the column Line (at the end of each line we can see something like Closed ([0-9]+ min).

However here my issue (maybe I'm confusing something obvious), when I try to sum the value group by host by using unwrap method, I do not understand the result at all :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7biw6.png)

I would expect something like 20 (addition of 17 + 3) and not only 17 repeat many times line by line.

Am I missing something obvious?
at the level I'm at now, any help would be most welcome :)

Comment: At 13:30 you had only values 0 and 17, so sun of 17 is correct. And storting with something like 16:18 you should start seeing 20.

Comment: If all you want to see is a result at the end of your time range - change type of your query from **Range** to **Instant**.

Comment: Thk, it works well ;)